# What's the reason for overusing of the word "revolution" in 1969?

Tags: history

According to [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=7&case_insensitive=on&content=revolution) there had been a rise in using the word "revolution" through 1986 and 1969.

**What could be the reason? could it be because of a special upheaval in the world?**

*Any answer is appreciated!*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's trivial and speculative

Comment: @Rohit ,  what's your definition of 'off-topic' ?

Comment: You will find a lot of statistical features in any data. Asking people to speculate for you, with little background, seems off topic to me.

Comment: @Rohit; yeah! you're right. But I think the word 'revolution' in a politics-oriented community is not that much off-topic. any way . . . I got kinda my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easily explained. 1968 is remembered as a year of political upheaval and change (see [Protests of 1968](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protests_of_1968)). These years saw protest movements and political upheaval in the West, but also among Pact of Warsaw members and in other countries. Many of these events had a profound effect over the following years,, e.g.:

- Czechoslovakia: [Prague Spring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prague_Spring)
- France: [May 1968](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/May_68)
- Germany: [German Student Movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_student_movement)
- Italy: [Years of Lead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Years_of_Lead_(Italy))
- Mexico: [Mexican Movement of 1968](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexican_Movement_of_1968)
- USA: [Vietnam War Protests](https://www.history.com/topics/vietnam-war/vietnam-war-protests), [Civil Rights Movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_rights_movement)

Furthermore, much of Africa had recently gained its independendence (see [Decolonisation of Africa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decolonisation_of_Africa)).

Other events that had a huge impact in 1969:

- [Landing on the Moon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon_landing)
- [Woodstock Festival](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodstock)